# Elastic.Apm.EntityFramework6.Ef6Interceptor, Elastic.Apm.EntityFramework6 registered in the application config

Tags: elasticsearch, migration

I am using Elastic Search in my MVC Application and getting en error when adding migration. Flow is:

- Integrate Elastic APM to project.
- add new property to model
- PM: add-migration somePropOnFooModel

There is an warnin message like that

> The type 'Elastic.Apm.EntityFramework6.Ef6Interceptor, Elastic.Apm.EntityFramework6' registered in the application config file as an IDbInterceptor not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application.

Answer (score 0):

I can by pass it when I comment entityframework->Interceptor node in web.config file

> 

```
  <interceptor type="Elastic.Apm.EntityFramework6.Ef6Interceptor, Elastic.Apm.EntityFramework6"/>
</interceptors>
```

And I can continue after uncomment it